# How does microsoftonline.com know which device I am on, and whether it is a registered device?

Tags: web-browser, oauth, microsoft

Most of the webprogramming and IT security I know is from ten years ago. I'm far from being a pro, so please keep my ignorance in mind when answering.

Back then, browsers sometimes sent details about the client in the headers. Eg browser version, OS and locale. But a client could choose not to send, or it could be changed to send whatever it liked, and the server had no way of knowing if the details were correct. Authentication was done with a password, or in special cases with some public key authentication implemented in Java or Javascript, and to my knowledge there was no such thing as registered devices.

When I try to log on login.microsoftonline.com with my company account, from any other PC than my work PC, I get the following error:

[image]

The interesting part is:

```
Device identifier: Not available
Device platform: Linux
Device state: Unregistered
```

The URL looks something like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=00000(...)
```

What is happening? Why is the browser on my work PC sending details about the client? And exactly what is it sending, and how is it sending it in a spoofproof, or at least hard to spoof fashion? Do all browsers support authenticating the underlying client in some way? Is this some new standard, or is it some proprietary concept that only exists on Windows machines? Can my Linux PC be set up to also be a "registered device". How?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, Linux is parsed from your user agent and M$ was not able to determine the rest.

Those fields are more useful for Windows 10 users or corporate devices with a registration policy. All major browsers have this integration:

- Edge (obvious first-party support)
- Chrome (requires group policy/add-on)
- Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/windows-sso

Unlike NTLM or Kerberos, this new implementation is safe over the public Internet with less privacy exposure. Only Microsoft's domains can see the account/device information.

You can search "Azure AD SSO" if you want more info.

Comment: There's more to it - probably a TLS client certificate stored in the windows certificate store...